# Getting day of year without DayOfYear Function?

Tags: c#, datetime, datetimepicker

I wish to get the current day of year (Feb 02 as 33 etc) without using the inbuilt DayOfYear function..
current day will soon be changed to a DateTime picker.
any response greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you want to use `DateTime.Now.DayOfYear`?

Comment: When you don't want to use the built in functionality, it helps if you can provide details of *why not*. If it's homework, fine, say so. If it's some particular restrictions in your environment, *detail* them - if the built in functionality isn't going to work, how do you know the suggested answers will, if people are operating blindly?

Answer (score 4):

Because I refuse to believe that there is a good reason for not using `DateTime.Now.DayOfYear`, and for those who may arrive at this question when looking for the proper way to calculate day of year, my answer is:

```
int dayOfYear = DateTime.Now.DayOfYear;
```

Answer (score 3):

Well you can calculate it yourself with a hard-coded array of "start of month" values (1, 32, 60, 90, 121 etc) and add 1 if you're in a leap year and the month is March or later... but why not just use the built-in property?

Alternatively, [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com) doesn't use `DateTime.DayOfYear` :)

```
// Ideally, use an injected IClock for testability...
var now = SystemClock.SystemNow.InZone(DateTimeZone.SystemDefault);
var dayOfYear = now.DayOfYear;
```

(Note that this uses the *system* time zone, which may not be appropriate if you're serving a page to a user in a different time zone. Think about that carefully.)

Answer (score 0):

You can just calculate it yourself:

```
protected int GetJulianDate(System.DateTime dDate)
{
    // CREATE THE JULIAN DATE FROM THE PROVIDED DATE
    //   dDate - THE DATE TO BE CONVERTED
    DateTime firstDay = DateTime.Parse("01/01/" + dDate.Year);
    TimeSpan ts = dDate.Subtract(firstDay);
    return ts.Days + 1;
}
```